# aggregation of rows of a column on the basis of data of another column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to aggregate first ib_data troubleshooting column  with all ob_data    which are coming between next ib_data.

```
 select *,
rank()OVER (PARTITION BY service_request_number ORDER BY (activity_created_date::timestamp) asc) AS flag,
case when activity_type ~* '(Inbound|Transfer Accepted|Chat|Dell Service Provider|fax|social)'::text then 'ib_data'
else  'ob_data'
end as activity_type_flag
from log_activity_view
where service_request_number='984213950'
```

here,st=service_tag,srn=service_request_number,ai=activity_id,acd=activity_created_date,atype=activity_type,atf=activity_type_flag
output is now:

```
st   srn   ai   acd          atype   troubleshooting flag     atf
1     2    a    2018-12-21      ib       ab            1      ib_data
1     2    b    2018-12-22      ob       pq            2      ob_data
1     2    c    2019-01-21      ib       xt            3      ib_data
```

I want output as

```
st   srn   ai   acd          atype   troubleshooting flag     atf
1     2    a    2018-12-21      ib       ab,pq            1      ib_data
```

Comment: You really have to explain your use case better. Why are these rows aggregated. What do you want to achieve? Maybe some column are not necessary as demonstration. Please provide: Use case, _MINIMIZED_ sample data and explain your expected output

Comment: ya the output i m getting the data will be same.i want to group by all ob_data and 1st ib_data which are coming between 2 ib_data.how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your whole problem. But what I understood was: You want to aggregate all `troubleshooting` values between two `atf = ibdata`.

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7ddb70449aa08a14511ff021afda8f1d)

You need to create groups per `atf`. This could be done with this:

```
-- first step, create summable column
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN atype = 'ib' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
    troubles
```

This adds a column with the values `1,0,1` to your rows.

This can be combined with a cumulative SUM window function:

```
-- second step, cumulative sum    
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN atype = 'ib' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY acd)
FROM
    troubles
```

This yields in values `(1,1,2)`. You can see, that now you have a criteria for grouping. Every `ib_data` value the count increases to a new group value.

Now you simply have to group by this new column:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(st) as st, MIN(srn) as srn, MIN(ai) as ai, 
    MIN(acd) as acd, MIN(atype) as atype,

    array_agg(trouble ORDER BY acd) as trouble, -- your aggregation

    MIN(flag) as flag, MIN(atf) as atf
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN atype = 'ib' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY acd)
    FROM
        troubles
) s
GROUP BY sum
```

Important is the `array_agg` (of course you could convert it into text if you want to.). Because you did't define what should happen with the other columns, for simplicity I assumed that they should be the minimum. (of course you could do it with first_value window function or something else)